# Laravel validation by database records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

> Problem is how to validate by Database model, I have model "Emails". I just want to people can register if their email already in our Email model.

**Email database table**

```
Schema::create('emails', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('username')->nullable();
        $table->text('fullname')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->text('email')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Auth@RegisterController**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name'     => 'required|max:255',
        'email'    => 'required|max:255|unique:users',         here i guess
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}**strong text**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `unique` validation for unique email in `users` table and `exists` validation to check email exists in `emails` table.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name'     => 'required|max:255',
        'email'    => 'required|max:255|unique:users|exists:emails',  
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

Assuming you have `email` field in both `users` and `emails` tables

Answer (score 1):

Did u try RULE-EXISTS?

exists:table,column

The field under validation must exist on a given database table.

More:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-exists

Comment: No i didn't try this. so then i must do it like this ? `'required|max:255|unique:tablename.columnname,email',`

Comment: yes, but not unique, use - exists: table_name, column_name